# error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations required

Tags: rust

I have a strange error when trying to compile this code :

```
pub trait ValueGiver<T> {
    fn give(_: Option<Self>) -> T;
}

struct m;

impl<f64> ValueGiver<f64> for m {
    fn give(_:Option<m>) -> f64 {
        0.5f64
    } 
}

fn main() {
    let y : f64 = ValueGiver::give(None::<m>);
}
```

[playpen](http://is.gd/NjBfAG)

(the option part is a trick to call static trait method)

I get :

```
c.rs:64:5: 68:6 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations required
c.rs:64     impl<f64> ValueGiver<f64> for m {
c.rs:65         fn give(_:Option<m>) -> f64 {
c.rs:66             0.5f64
c.rs:67         } 
c.rs:68     }
```

I dont know what part is not clear for inference, and the error message is not very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace `impl<f64>` with just `impl`.** You don't want a generic impl, you want a specific impl. You'd write `impl<T>` to **define** type parameters that you can use later in the impl; you don't need that here.

When you write `impl<f64>`, this `f64` is interpreted as a type parameter. However, all other occurrences of `f64` in the impl are interpreted as the `f64` keyword, which designates the primitive `f64` type. The compiler is complaining because it is not able to infer a concrete type for the `f64` type parameter.

If we replace `impl<f64>` with `impl<T>`, [we get the same error](http://is.gd/6jJJVl).

Comment: Thanks ! it was a stupid mistake, sorry. Still the error message could be more clear. Is it enough to open an issue ?

Comment: Yeah, you could file an issue to disallow keywords as type parameters.

Comment: `f64` is not a keyword. It’s just a perfectly ordinary identifier than happens to refer to a built-in type. The problem is solely that it’s saying “about \`_\`” rather than “about \`f64\`”.

Comment: Oh yeah, if `f64` was a keyword, then there couldn't be a module named `f64`... I think the `_` may come from an implicit `::<_>`.

Comment: @BigEpsilon: Anytime an error message is not clear, it is enough to open an issue about it. Whether it will be closed or relegated to low-priority is another matter... especially since in Open Source anybody finding the issue worth its time could try and fix it.